# What is the Xpath expression to select all nodes that have text when using the Firefox WebDriver?

Tags: firefox, xpath, selenium, webdriver

I would like to select all nodes, that have text in them.

In this example the outer `shouldBeIgnored` tag, should not be selected:

```
<shouldBeIgnored>
    <span>
        the outer Span should be selected
    </span>
</shouldBeIgnored>
```

Some other posts suggest something like this: `//*/text()`.

However, this doesn't work in firefox.

This is a small UnitTest to reproduce the problem:

```
 public class XpathTest {
    final WebDriver webDriver   = new FirefoxDriver();

    @Test
    public void shouldNotSelectIgnoredTag() {

        this.webDriver.get("http://www.s2server.de/stackoverflow/11773593.html");

        System.out.println(this.webDriver.getPageSource());

        final List<WebElement> elements = this.webDriver.findElements(By.xpath("//*/text()"));

        for (final WebElement webElement : elements) {
            assertEquals("span", webElement.getTagName());
        }
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        this.webDriver.quit();
    }
 }
```

Comment: xPath is not reliable for Selenium2 (webdriver).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i found out that there is no way to do it with xpath (because XPaths `text()` selects also the innerText of a node). As workaround i have to inject Java Script that returns all elements, selected by an XPath, that has some text.

Like this:

```
public class XpathTest
{
    //@formatter:off
    final static String JS_SCRIPT_GET_TEXT  =  "function trim(str) {                                                       " +                                                                                                                                             
                                               "    return str.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'');            " +                                                                                                                                             
                                               "}                                                                          " +                                                                                                                                             
                                               "                                                                           " +                                                                                                                                             
                                               "function extractText(element) {                                            " +                                                                                                                                             
                                               "    var text = '';                                                         " +                                                                                                                                             
                                               "    for ( var i = 0; i < element.childNodes.length; i++) {                 " +                                                                                                                                             
                                               "        if (element.childNodes[i].nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {           " +                                                                                                                                             
                                               "            nodeText = trim(element.childNodes[i].textContent);            " +                                                                                                                                             
                                               "                                                                           " +                                                                                                                                             
                                               "            if (nodeText) {                                                " +                                                                                                                                             
                                               "                text += element.childNodes[i].textContent + ' ';           " +                                                                                                                                             
                                               "            }                                                              " +                                                                                                                                             
                                               "        }                                                                  " +                                                                                                                                             
                                               "    }                                                                      " +                                                                                                                                             
                                               "                                                                           " +                                                                                                                                             
                                               "    return trim(text);                                                     " +                                                                                                                                             
                                               "}                                                                          " +                                                                                                                                             
                                               "                                                                           " +                                                                                                                                             
                                               "function selectElementsHavingTextByXPath(expression) {                     " +                                                                                                                                             
                                               "                                                                           " +                                                                                                                                             
                                               "    result = document.evaluate(\".\" + expression, document.body, null,    " +                                                                                                                                             
                                               "            XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);                                   " +                                                                                                                                             
                                               "                                                                           " +                                                                                                                                             
                                               "    var nodesWithText = new Array();                                       " +                                                                                                                                             
                                               "                                                                           " +                                                                                                                                             
                                               "    var node = result.iterateNext();                                       " +                                                                                                                                             
                                               "    while (node) {                                                         " +                                                                                                                                             
                                               "        if (extractText(node)) {                                           " +                                                                                                                                             
                                               "            nodesWithText.push(node)                                       " +                                                                                                                                             
                                               "        }                                                                  " +                                                                                                                                             
                                               "                                                                           " +                                                                                                                                             
                                               "        node = result.iterateNext();                                       " +                                                                                                                                             
                                               "    }                                                                      " +                                                                                                                                             
                                               "                                                                           " +                                                                                                                                             
                                               "    return nodesWithText;                                                  " +                                                                                                                                             
                                               "}                                                                          " +                                                                                                                                             
                                               "return selectElementsHavingTextByXPath(arguments[0]);";                                                                                                                                                                                    
    //@formatter:on

    final WebDriver     webDriver           = new FirefoxDriver();

    @Test
    public void shouldNotSelectIgnoredTag()
    {
        this.webDriver.get("http://www.s2server.de/stackoverflow/11773593.html");

        final List<WebElement> elements = (List<WebElement>) ((JavascriptExecutor) this.webDriver).executeScript(JS_SCRIPT_GET_TEXT, "//*");

        assertFalse(elements.isEmpty());

        for (final WebElement webElement : elements)
        {
            assertEquals("span", webElement.getTagName());
        }
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown()
    {
        this.webDriver.quit();
    }

}
```

I modified the UnitTest that the example testable.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to select all nodes that contain text then you can use

```
//*[text()]
```

Above xpath will look for any element which contains text. Notice the `text()` function which is used to determine if current node has text or not.

In your case it will select `<span>` tag as it contains text.

Comment: Sadly your expression will select also the `shouldBeIgnored` node, because its child has text.

Comment: @ChristianSchneider No it doesn't. You can validate it [here](http://www.mizar.dk/XPath/Default.aspx). I think it won't select because it this xpath is looking for text of current node and node `<shouldBeIgnored>` itself does not have any text.

Answer (score 1):

You can call a javascript function, which shall return you text nodes:

```
function GetTextNodes(){    
var lastNodes = new Array();
    $("*").each(function(){
      if($(this).children().length == 0)
        lastNodes.push($(this));
    });
    return lastNodes;
}
```

Selenium WebDriver code:

```
IJavaScriptExecutor jscript = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
List<IWebElement> listTextNodes = jscript.ExecuteScript("return GetTextNodes();");
```

FYI: Something like might work for you.

Comment: This is interesting, i will try it.

Comment: You assume that there is jQuery ($). Could you edit the code that jQuery is not needed?

Comment: Sorry, I am extremely poor at JavaScript.

Comment: Without jQuery you could pre-load the above Javascript using a method like this one:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17385779/how-do-i-load-a-javascript-file-into-the-dom-using-selenium

Answer (score 1):

I see no reason why this wouldn't work
(by java)

```
text = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span")).getText()
```

If in the odd case that doesnt work:

```
text = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span")).getAttribute("innerHTML")
```

Comment: You are selecting all `span`s. I need to select all elements having text. That is is different requirement. If i select all objects and then test them with `.getText()` whehter they have text, the operation will be very slow because it will select hunderds of not needed webElements and afterwords for all this webElements I have to call .getText()

Answer (score 1):

One problem with locating text nodes is that even empty strings are considered as valid text nodes (e.g

```
<tag1><tag2/></tag1>
```

has no text nodes but

```
<tag1>  <tag2/>    </tag1>
```

has 2 text nodes, one with 2 spaces and another with 4 spaces )

If you want only the text nodes that have non-empty text, here is one way to do it:

```
//text()[string-length(normalize-space(.))>0]
```

or to get their parent elements

```
//*[text()[string-length(normalize-space(.))>0]]
```

Comment: Returning text nodes is fine as far as XPath goes but if you pass a path to a Selenium method and the path resolves to *anything else* than elements, then Selenium will choke.