# How to execute a JavaScript function defined in the website script with Selenium?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am working with a website and I need to run a couple js code with Selenium. To make things easier, I need to run functions declared in the website scripts.
For example, the website use a script file called `document_handler.js` with the following code:

```
 (function ($) {
     var getConversationId = function(){
         return $('input[name="conversationId"]').val()
     };
 })(jQuery);
```

In Selenium, if I run:

```
js_eval = driver.execute_script("return getConversationId()")
```

I get:

> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: getConversationId is not defined

And if I run:

```
js_eval = driver.execute_script("return $.getConversationId()")
```

I get:

> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: $.getConversationId is not a function

How can I load the website javascript files so I can use its functions inside Selenium? Or there is something wrong with my code?

Comment: is it `obterConversationId` or `getConversationId` ?

Comment: However, the function is in a closed scope, you cannot access it, even from the console..

Comment: @webdeb fixed, it was a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a script you have access to, you have to make the function available to the outer/global scope.. The simplest would be to assign it to the window object, and it should work.

```
(function ($) {
     window.getConversationId = function(){
         return $('input[name="conversationId"]').val()
     };
 })(jQuery);
```

OR this way, which is basically the same..

```
var getConversationId;
(function ($) {
     getConversationId = function(){
         return $('input[name="conversationId"]').val()
     };
 })(jQuery);
```

Comment: This is a Script loaded by the page, not written by me. I can download it and edit, but I am not sure how to make Selenium load the edited script and ignore the original

Comment: Can this be wrapped in a JSE call?

Comment: @TalesPádua I would love to answer you the special selenium question with script replacing??, but I not an expert, you should open a new question and describe the problem more precisely, don't forget to vote and accept ;)

Comment: You can change the modified script only on the webserver but that does not seem intended.

Comment: I will try to change the script and inject it following this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17385779/how-do-i-load-a-javascript-file-into-the-dom-using-selenium)