# Modifying the Javascript Navigator object with Selenium

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, web-scraping

I tried accessing a site with Selenium (with geckodriver) and it said I was blocked but I can access it manually with the Firefox Browser. So I compared the components of my fingerpirnt and the only difference was that in the Navigator object "webdriver" was set to "true" when I used Selenium. I tried running this code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
firefox_binary = '/usr/bin/firefox'
options = Options()
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
caps = DesiredCapabilities().FIREFOX
# caps["pageLoadStrategy"] = "normal"  #  complete
caps["pageLoadStrategy"] = "eager"  #  interactive
injected_javascript=("Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', { value: 'false' })")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'/home/kkkk/ggecko/geckodriver', firefox_binary=firefox_binary)
driver.get('https://auth.citromail.hu/regisztracio/')

driver.execute_async_script(injected_javascript)
```

but it just loaded page with "webdriver" still set to "true", then returned this message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kkkk/driverr.py", line 14, in <module>
    driver.execute_async_script(injected_javascript)
  File "/home/kkkk/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 652, in execute_async_script
    'args': converted_args})['value']
  File "/home/kkkk/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 314, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/kkkk/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: Timed out
```

What am I doing wrong or is there a different way of accomplishing this?

Comment: The script needs to be injected before the page is loaded. try this: https://intoli.com/blog/making-chrome-headless-undetectable/

Answer (score 2):

Refer to this issue:
[Selenium webdriver: firefox headless inject javascript to modify browser property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51439377/selenium-webdriver-firefox-headless-inject-javascript-to-modify-browser-propert)

it provides a useful pathway.

This is the code:

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
options=webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
options.set_headless(True)
driver=webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
# solution found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17385779/how-do-i-load-a-javascript-file-into-the-dom-using-selenium
driver.execute_script("var s=window.document.createElement('script'); s.src='javascriptFirefox.js';window.document.head.appendChild(s);")
driver.get('https://auth.citromail.hu/regisztracio/')
```

Javascript file `javascriptFirefox.js`

```
// overwrite the `languages` property to use a custom getter
const setProperty = () => {
    Object.defineProperty(navigator, "languages", {
        get: function() {
            return ["en-US", "en", "es"];
        }
    });

    // Overwrite the `plugins` property to use a custom getter.
    Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'plugins', {
        get: () => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    });

    // Pass the Webdriver test
    Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', {
      get: () => false,
    });
    callback();
};
setProperty();
```

Comment: it won't work after the page is loaded, have you even tried what you wrote?

Comment: Another potential issue, you want to have the webdriver = `undefined`, `false` is a giveaway