# How to Add a <script> into Head Using Selenium's JavascriptExecutor

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

## Summary

I want to figure out a way to add a `<script>` tag into the head of DOM using `Selenium`'s `JavascriptExecutor`, or any other way of doing this would be nice.

---

I have tried many ways and also found a few similar topics and none of them solved my problem which is why I felt the need to ask it on here.

For example :

[Suggested solutions in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17385779/how-do-i-load-a-javascript-file-into-the-dom-using-selenium) did not solve my problem. Some people say it worked for them but nope, it didn't for me.

---

### What I've been trying to execute?

Here is the small snippet of the code that I want to execute:

```java
            WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

            jse.executeScript("var s = document.createElement('script');");
            jse.executeScript("s.type = 'text/javascript';");
            jse.executeScript("s.text = 'function foo() {console.log('foo')}';");
            jse.executeScript("window.document.head.appendChild(s);");
```

I just skipped the code above where you navigate to a webpage using `driver.get()` etc. and then try to execute the scripts.

Also, `s.text` would contain the actual script that I want to use so I just put there a `foo()` function just to give the idea.

#### The above code throws this error when you run it:

`Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException: ReferenceError: s is not defined`

---

So far I've tried every possible solution I could find on the Internet but none of them seems to work.

Comment: Does a variable declared inside a JavaScriptExecutor persist after its script is finished? Could be wrong but I don’t think so.

Comment: No, it does not. That is the problem. You can read the error I got above. It says the variable is not defined. Besides that, I also tried injecting the whole JavaScript file but that does not work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP came up with the following solution:

```
jse.executeScript("var s=window.document.createElement('script');" + 
"s.type = 'text/javascript';" + "s.text = function foo() {console.log('foo')};" + 
"window.document.head.appendChild(s);");
```

Comment: I just tried this but there is something wrong with this "\" character. I mean can we even use this in Java? Because when I tried I got all errors. However, when I tried it with `+` concatenating all the strings and also after deleting single quotes around function definition, it worked fine.

`jse.executeScript("var s=window.document.createElement('script');" +
                    "s.type = 'text/javascript';" +
            "s.text = function foo() {console.log('foo')};" +
            "window.document.head.appendChild(s);");`

Answer (score 1):

For one, this line is invalid.

```
    jse.executeScript("s.text = 'function foo() {console.log('foo')}';");
```

Note how you wrap single-quote text in single quotes. Use one set as "\""

I would personally do this by doing (edited to make it a global function):

```
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.Extensions;

driver.ExecuteJavascript("window.foo = function foo() {console.log('foo')}");
```

It's as simple as that. You are registering foo as a method by doing this. After you execute this javascript, you can manually go in to the browser developer tools and call "foo()" to check. Additionally, you can check this by registering it directly in the console. Just enter "function foo() {console.log('foo')}" into your browser console, and then call "foo()".

No need to add this as a script tag.

EDIT #2: I fixed my above code suggestion so that the method is assigned to the window, and thus accessible globally, and outside of the anonymous script that javascript executor runs the code in. The original issues with this not working are resolved by this, at least in my testing of it.

Comment: Well, first of all, thank you for correcting me about quotes. You are right about that. But you are wrong about what you suggested later. If I just execute that script and go to console and try calling `foo()` then I get `foo is not defined` even though the code terminated successfully.

Comment: I added an example of how I use this as an edit to the above post. Note that I define the method as originally suggested, but unlike originally suggested, I also consume the method right after I define it. It is possible that the method only exists within that executor session. If that is the case, and you do not want to do that, It may indeed be best to add a script tag.

Comment: Yes, page is not refreshing. By the way I tried C. Peck's solution and combined your suggestion (I mean using double quotes and single quotes properly) then it worked fine. And I wanted to add it as a script tag because I will use a JS file which contains a few functions so I would like to use the functions later on the page too.

Comment: And by the way you may be right because this is what it says on the javadoc -- "*Executes JavaScript in the context of the currently selected frame or window. The script fragment provided will be executed as the body of an anonymous function.

Within the script, use document to refer to the current document. **Note that local variables will not be available once the script has finished executing, though global variables will persist.*** " [link](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html#executeScript-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-)

Comment: I updated my suggestion. It works when I assign it directly to the window like so:

driver.ExecuteJavascript("window.foo = function foo() {console.log('foo')}");

I confirmed that doing the above, and simply calling "foo()" works exactly as you originally intended. So it has the added benefit of maybe being cleaner and more concise than the suggested code.